# Using a sorted DataSet WPF C#

Tags: c#, sorting, dataset

Let's say I have a DataSet with one table. This table has two columns: id, name. Some random values:

```
  0 John
  1 Michael
  2 Alice
  3 Bob
```

I sorted a DataSet:

```
dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "name";
```

Also, I have a listBox to show this sorted DataSet:

```
lb.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

And it shows like I want:

```
 Alice
 Bob
 John
 Michael
```

BUT I additionally have a MouseDoubleClick event for the listBox to show a MessageBox with the id number. And here's my problem - I can't figure it out why the id numbers are not sorted - for example Alice should have "2" but when I double-click on Alice, the MessageBox shows "0" (Bob 1, John 2, Michael 3). So, how to sort a DataSet permanently? (I know this example is kind of weird but only want to get a way to do it).

UPDATE

MouseDoubleClick code:

```
 MessageBox.Show(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[lb.SelectedIndex][0].ToString());
```

Comment: can you update the question with the code `MouseDoubleClick `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting your list box source like this:

```
lb.ItemsSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

... and you're retrieving the ID like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[lb.SelectedIndex][0].ToString());
```

You're not accessing the `DefaultView` when you're retrieving the ID.  You're accessing the `DataTable` directly.

Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView[lb.SelectedIndex][0].ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect! I knew there was something to do with the DefaultView but I didn't know how to do it. Thank you, you saved my life :)